# can NSAsynchronousFetchRequest understand changes in Persistent store?

Tags: asynchronous, ios8, nsfetchrequest

I've implemented a sample about NSAsynchronousFetchRequest, the same as this tutorial:
[tutsplus:iOS 8: Core Data and Asynchronous Fetching](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-core-data-and-asynchronous-fetching--cms-22241)
this request just executes at first load of view and fetch records asynch, but it can't understand changes made in persistent store, (the thing that NSFetchedResultController do)
my question is that, can NSAsynchFetchRequest understand changes automatically (the same as NSFetchedResultsController)?

Comment: "The NSAsynchronous*Requests are designed to NOT WORK with the NSFetchedResultsController." - [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6196)